# How to loop through a struct

Tags: c#

I have the following struct:-

```
public struct Cordination
{
    public int A;
    public int B;

    public Cordination(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}
```

And then i need to calculate the distance between any two places, so i need to loop through the struct and substract the x-axis of each places and the y-axis to get the distance between any two places in the struct and then return the shortest distance; But i am not sure how i can do that :-

```
public float distanceInMeter(Cordination[] cordination)
{
    for (i //codes goes here...)
}
```

Comment: Can you merge your questions(http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13000282/how-to-substract-the-values-of-a-multi-demensional-array#13000282) and rephrase them.

Comment: SquareRoot(A*A + B*B)? Are you seeking how the find the distance between two points, the length of a vector, or... I don't even understand how looping in anything come into play.

Comment: the cordination struct should have values such as (1,2) (6,5) etc, so i need to substract the x-axis & y-axis of each cordination to calculate the distance between any cordination and then return the minimume distance between any of these cordinations...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the answer to your question. You need to fix one coordinate and calculate distances to all others but trying not to repeat calculations. Therefore `i` will fix one coordinate and `j` will iterate through all others. Note that `j` is starting from `i + 1` ensuring that you don't repeat calculations.

```
public struct Cordination
{
    public int A;
    public int B;

    public Cordination(int a, int b)
    {
        A = a;
        B = b;
    }
}

public float distanceInMeter(Cordination[] cordination)
{
    float minDistance = float.MaxValue;
    for (int i = 0; i < cordination.Length - 1; i++)
    {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < cordination.Length; j++)
        {
            float dist = (float)Math.Sqrt(
                Math.Pow(cordination[i].A - cordination[j].A, 2.0) +
                Math.Pow(cordination[i].B - cordination[j].B, 2.0));
            if (dist < minDistance)
                minDistance = dist;
        }
    }
    return minDistance;
}
```

Comment: Good grief... I'm impressed you managed to make something out of that question. I just couldn't figure out what he wanted.

Comment: @Marc-AndréJutras Well, although I think cordination refers to coordinate and float is for distance although he uses integers for A and B (I presume X and Y), I have seen too many such similar questions so I could find out what he wanted. I didn't want to change his code, only to help him to continue his work. Thanks for the comment. I

Answer (score 0):

Okay you should generate an list

```
 List<Cordination> TestList = new List<Cordination>();
```

Next you put your Elements in the List

```
 TestList.Add(new Cordination(5,6);
```

Now you can go with a foreach loop or an for loop trough the list

```
  foreach (Cordination i in TestList)
    {
       Console.WriteLine(i.A);
    }
```

If you have more Questions about this:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx